# Regular expression problem (extracting one text or another)

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, text

I have problem with regex. I've been playing with it for three hours and I didn't find out anything working.

I have this text:

```
Fax received from 45444849 ( 61282370000 )
```

And I need to extract the number from brackets, so I will get `61282370000`. If there is nothing (or whitespaces only) in brackets it should take the number before brackets. I have only managed to do this expression, which takes the number from brackets correctly:

```
Fax received from .* \(\s([^)]*)\s\)$
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would advise that rather than trying to construct a regex which takes either that you construct a regex which takes the one in the brackets - if this fails then another regex takes the one before...

Comment: The problem is, that I have to setup application, which can take only one result group (either the number from brackets, or the number before, if there is nothing in brackets). If I have the possibility to edit it on application level, I would do it rather, than finding this solution, but I can't. I've tried the alternate symbol "|", but I haven't done anything useful.

Comment: Try using "||". For eg.`/\(\s*(\d+)/||/(\d+)/` achieves the same thing. The matched no. will always be present in $1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the regex /(\d+)(?!\D*\d+)/
It uses negative lookahead to capture the last number in the string.

For eg.

```
perl -le '$_="Fax received from 45444849 ( 61282370000 )"; /(\d+)(?!\D*\d+)/; print $1'
```

will give you 61282370000. However,

```
perl -le '$_="Fax received from 45444849 (  )"; /(\d+)(?!\D*\d+)/; print $1'
```

gives 45444849 in $1

Answer (score 1):

You should try to match on both... then use `if`... assume the data is in `$line`...

```
$line =~ /Fax\sreceived.+?(\d+)\s+\(\s*(\S+)?\s+\)/;
if ($2) {$result= $2;} else {$result= $1;}
```

Examples...

```
$line1 = "Fax received from 45444849 ( 61282370000 )";
$line1 =~ /Fax\sreceived.+?(\d+)\s+\(\s*(\S+)?\s+\)/;
if ($2) {$result= $2;} else {$result= $1;}
print "result1: $result\n";

$line2 = "Fax received from 95551212 ( )";
$line2 =~ /Fax\sreceived.+?(\d+)\s+\(\s*(\S+)?\s+\)/;
if ($2) {$result= $2;} else {$result= $1;}
print "result2: $result\n";
```

Running that yields...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ perl fax.pl
result1: 61282370000
result2: 95551212
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode...

```
if str.match("\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)") 
   return str.matches("\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)")[0]
else
   return str.matches("(\d+)")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle PL/SQL, I should write as follows:

```
SELECT TRIM (
          REPLACE (
             REPLACE (
                REGEXP_REPLACE (
                   'Fax received from 323 ( 123 )',
                   '[ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]*( [0123456789]* )',
                   '',
                   1,
                   1,
                   'cm'),
                ')',
                ''),
             '(',
             ''))
  FROM DUAL;
```

The result of the SELECTed expression is 123.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why you're posting a SQL query as a response to this question

Answer (score 1):

If this *is* perl, you don't need to do the selection logic in the regex. You simply need to capture *both* and select, like so:

```
my $number = List::Util::first { $_; } m/(\d{7,})\s*[(]\s*(\d{7,})?\s*[)]/;
# deal with $number...
```